# f2py array valued functions

Tags: python, function, numpy, fortran, f2py

Do recent versions of f2py support wrapping array-valued fortran functions?
In some ancient documentation this wasn't supported. How about it now?

Let's for example save the following function as func.f95.

```
function func(x)
    implicit none
    double precision :: x(:),func(size(x))
    integer :: i
    do i=1,size(x)
        func(i) = i*x(i)
    end do
end function
```

I compile this with `f2py --fcompiler=gnu95 -c -m func func.f95`

Then let the following python code be test_func.py

```
import func
from numpy import array

x = array(xrange(1,10),dtype='float64')
print 'x=',x

y = func.func(x)
print 'func(x)=',y
```

The output from
`python test_func.py` is

```
x= [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: you can do [the workaround explained in this answer...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17474225/832621), but it will require more evaluations than required. For this case I'd go for `Cython`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism of f2py turns Fortran *subroutines* into python functions.  It doesn't understand how to turn a Fortran *function* into a python function.  I have found that I need to wrap all Fortran functions with a subroutine, or even better, rewrite them as subroutines.

Comment: Is f2py **that** powerful? Is it reliable enough that writing the whole fortran codebase in this special way is a fair price?

Comment: I've never had problems with reliability, but like I said, it is frustrating.  Personally, I only use it for small projects because of the restrictions it imposes.  There is another tool, [fwrap](http://fwrap.sourceforge.net/), that is supposed to be better than f2py, but I haven't tested it.