# f2py, Python function that returns an array (vector-valued function)

Tags: python, numpy, cython, f2py, numerical-integration

In the following Python I have five functions contained in the array returned by `func` which I have to integrate. The code calls an external Fortran module generated using `f2py`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin , exp
from trapzdv import trapzdv
def func(x):
    return np.array([x**2, x**3, cos(x), sin(x), exp(x)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs = np.linspace(0.,20.,100)
    ans =  trapzdv(func,xs,5)
    print 'from Fortran:', ans
    print 'exact:', np.array([20**3/3., 20**4/4., sin(20.), -cos(20.), exp(20.)])
```

The Fortran routine is:

```
      subroutine trapzdv(f,xs,nf,nxs,result)
          integer :: I
          double precision :: x1,x2
          integer, intent(in) :: nf, nxs
          double precision, dimension(nf) :: fx1,fx2
          double precision, intent(in), dimension(nxs) :: xs
          double precision, intent(out), dimension(nf) :: result
          external :: f 
          result = 0.0
          do I = 2,nxs
            x1 = xs(I-1)
            x2 = xs(I)
            fx1 = f(x1)
            fx2 = f(x2)
            result = result + (fx1+fx2)*(x2-x1)/2
          enddo
          return
      end
```

The problem is that Fortran is only integrating the first function in `func(x)`.
See the print result:

```
from Fortran: [ 2666.80270721  2666.80270721  2666.80270721  2666.80270721  2666.80270721]
exact: [  2.66666667e+03   4.00000000e+04   9.12945251e-01  -4.08082062e-01 4.85165195e+08]
```

One way to workarond that is to modify `func(x)` to return the value of a given
position in the array of functions:

```
def func(x,i):
    return np.array([x**2, x**3, cos(x), sin(x), exp(x)])[i-1]
```

And then change the Fortran routine to call the function with two parameters:

```
      subroutine trapzdv(f,xs,nf,nxs,result)
          integer :: I
          double precision :: x1,x2,fx1,fx2
          integer, intent(in) :: nf, nxs
          double precision, intent(in), dimension(nxs) :: xs
          double precision, intent(out), dimension(nf) :: result
          external :: f 
          result = 0.0
          do I = 2,nxs
            x1 = xs(I-1)
            x2 = xs(I)
            do J = 1,nf
                fx1 = f(x1,J)
                fx2 = f(x2,J)
                result(J) = result(J) + (fx1+fx2)*(x2-x1)/2
            enddo
          enddo
          return
      end
```

Which works:

```
from Fortran: [  2.66680271e+03   4.00040812e+04   9.09838195e-01   5.89903440e-01 4.86814128e+08]
exact: [  2.66666667e+03   4.00000000e+04   9.12945251e-01  -4.08082062e-01 4.85165195e+08]
```

But here `func` is called 5 times more than necessary (in the real case `func`
has above 300 functions, so it will be called 300 times more than necessary).

- Does anyone know a better solution to make Fortran recognizes all the array returned by `func(x)`? In other words, make Fortran build `fx1 = f(x1)` as an array with 5 elements corresponding to the functions in `func(x)`.

---

OBS: I am compiling using `f2py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m trapzdv trapzdv.f90`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot return the array from the python function into Fortran.  You would need a subroutine for that (meaning it is called with the `call` statement), and this is something that `f2py` does not let you do.

In Fortran 90 you can create functions that return arrays, but again this is not something that `f2py` can do, especially since your function is not a Fortran function.

Your only option is to use your looping workaround, or a redesign of how you want python and Fortran to interact.

Answer (score 1):

Despite this answer does not solve the question, it is a workaround doing the same in Cython. Here the trapezoidal rule and a polynomial integrator are implemented for a vector-valued function. The code below I put in a `integratev.pyx`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
cimport numpy as np
FLOAT = np.float32
ctypedef np.float_t FLOAT_t

def trapzv(f, np.ndarray xs, int nf):
    cdef int nxs = xs.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray ans = np.zeros(nf, dtype=FLOAT)
    cdef double x1, x2
    for i in range(1,nxs):
        x1 = xs[i-1]
        x2 = xs[i]
        ans += (f(x2)+f(x1))*(x2-x1)/2.
    return ans

def poly(f, np.ndarray xs, int nf, int order=2):
    cdef int nxs = xs.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray ans = np.zeros(nf, dtype=FLOAT)
    cdef np.ndarray xis = np.zeros(order+1, dtype=FLOAT)
    cdef np.ndarray ais
    if nxs % (order+1) != 0:
        raise ValueError("poly: The size of xs must be a multiple of 'order+1'")
    for i in range(order,nxs,order):
        xis = xs[i-order:i+1]
        X = np.concatenate([(xis**i)[:,None] for i in range(order+1)], axis=1)
        ais = np.dot( inv(X), f(xis).transpose() )
        for k in range(1,order+2):
            ans += ais[k-1,:]/k * (xis[-1]**k - xis[0]**k)
    return ans
```

The following test was used:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin , exp
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import integratev
from subprocess import Popen
def func(x):
    return np.array([x**2, x**3, cos(x), sin(x), exp(x)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs = np.linspace(0.,20.,33)
    print 'exact:', np.array([20**3/3., 20**4/4., sin(20.), -cos(20.)+1, exp(20.)-1])
    ans =  integratev.trapzv(func,xs,5)
    print 'trapzv:', ans
    ans =  integratev.poly(func,xs,5,2)
    print 'poly:', ans
```

Giving:

```
exact: [  2.66666667e+03   4.00000000e+04   9.12945251e-01   5.91917938e-01 4.85165194e+08]
trapzv: [  2.66796875e+03   4.00390625e+04   8.83031547e-01   5.72522998e-01 5.00856448e+08]
poly: [  2.66666675e+03   4.00000000e+04   9.13748980e-01   5.92435718e-01 4.85562144e+08]
```

The poly can be of any order, which will probably give better results for most of the cases...