# sympy, obtaining the upper triangle of a symmetric matrix as a flattened array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sympy

I have the following symmetric matrix in `sympy`:

```
m = sympy.Matrix([[x**2, x**3, x**4],
                  [x**3, x**5, x**6],
                  [x**4, x**6, x**7]])
```

My goal is to obtain the upper triangle of this matrix as a flattened array, like `[x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6, x**7]`, that can be processed by `lambdify`.

I used In `numpy` to auxiiate achieving this:

```
f = lambdify((x), sympy.Matrix(np.array(m)[np.triu_indices(m.shape[0])]))
```

So that `f(2.)` gives:

```
[[   4.    8.   16.   32.   64.  128.]]
```

The questions is:

- is there a native way to do this in `sympy`?

Bonus:

- is there a way to obtain a `1D-array` instead of a `matrix`?

Comment: is there any specific reason you prefer a sympy solution over a numpy one? Because otherwise, sympy is quite slow compared to numpy  EDIT: hmm you are the same guy from the previous question about using sympy, ;-) assuming you will change something in your code to avoid the integration than? or is it not related to that other question?

Comment: Yes, I am the same guy... this is totally related to the other question. I could achieve a [great integration performance using Cython, check here...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17522695/832621)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a function to do that directly in SymPy yet (but patches are welcome!). You could probably write one pretty easily.

One thing you can try is using `cse`

```
>>> print cse(a)
([(x0, x**3), (x1, x**4), (x2, x**6)], [Matrix([
[x**2,   x0,   x1],
[  x0, x**5,   x2],
[  x1,   x2, x**7]])])
```

This will keep you from evaluating the same expression more than once. If your actual expression really is just powers of `x`, you can probably code up something even more efficient by using the fact that there is a lot of duplicate work involved in computing all the powers of `x`.