# Segmentation fault: 11 - running fortran wrapped in python

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py, fortran95

I am new to Fortran and I am trying to run fortran inside python using f2py. I have had luck when the fortran function gave output as a single value. But when I modified the fortran function to give out an array, I am getting segmentation faults.
Could someone please help me out? 
Here is the code:

Fortran function: in file called 'fortfunc.f95':

```
function fut(x,n) 
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: x
integer, intent(in) :: n
real, dimension(2) :: fut

! My aim is to return an array fut which has 2 elements in it

fut(1)=x*n
fut(2)=x*n*100


end function fut
```

Then I use f2py to compile fortran function to be used in python:

```
f2py -c -m func fortfunc.f95
```

here func is name of module to be imported in python

Python code: (pretty straightforward)

```
import func # func is the name of module which contains function fut
x=20
n=20
res=func.fut(x,n)
print('answer is ',res)
```

I wish to get an array with 2 elements called 'res' but instead I get 
    'Segmentation fault: 11'

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: What you want is not possible. You have to create a subroutine and pass the array in. You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474225/f2py-python-function-that-returns-an-array-vector-valued-function

Answer (score 3):

If you work with a subroutine, you could create the return array before you call the function. In that case, your Python script would be as following

```
import func
import numpy as np

res = np.zeros(2)
x = 20
n = 20
func.fut(res, x, n)

print("answer is", res)
```

And in the Fortran code, you can create a subroutine. Note that I replaced the type by `double precision` as a Fortran `real` is a single precision floating point number by default, while Python uses double precision.

```
subroutine fut(a,x,n) 
    implicit none
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double precision, intent(inout), dimension(2) :: a 

    ! My aim is to return an array fut which has 2 elements in it
    a(1) = x*n
    a(2) = x*n*100
end subroutine fut
```

Comment: Great! this works for now. Thanks @Chiel!
Also wondering if there is any way Fortran functions could have array/matrix as outputs?

Comment: The statement that " a Fortran real is a single precision floating point number by default, while Python uses double precision " does not precisely hold. `real` is simply the default kind, which depends on the compiler options and the platform, and `double precision` only gives twice the `real` size in bytes. Better to use `real32` and `real64` from `fortran_iso_env` module instead of `real` and `double precision` which are platform dependent.